# What is automatically populating this column?

Tags: mysql, timestamp

I am using MySQL 5.6.1 on a Win 7 64Bit.

I have a standard audit column I add to all my tables called CRT_TS (create timestamp), along with a UPD_TS (update timestamp) column.  I had planned on populating these via a before insert trigger and a before update trigger using utc_timestamp().

The UPD_TS column behaves as I expect it to.  However, the CRT_TS column seems to be getting automatically populated without my defining a default or trigger for that column.

I was able to reproduce this behavior by running the following script.

```
create schema `test` default character set utf8 collate utf8_general_ci;

drop table test.TEST_TABLE;

create table test.TEST_TABLE(
    TEST_ID             int             not null    auto_increment ,

    CRT_TS              timestamp       not null ,
    UPD_TS              timestamp       not null ,

    TEST_ALIAS          varchar(64)     not null ,
primary key   PK_PERM (TEST_ID) ,
unique  index UI_PERM_01 (TEST_ALIAS) )
auto_increment = 1001;

insert into test.TEST_TABLE
(TEST_ID
,TEST_ALIAS)
values
(1
,'testing');

select *
from   test.TEST_TABLE;
```

In the above example, the CRT_TS column isn't being supplied a value, and yet it is being populated with the same value what would have been provided by the now() function.  The UPD_TS column is populated with all zeros, yet both columns have been defined identically.

My questions is, what is populating the CRT_TS column?  I am attempting to set both the UPD_TS and CRT_TS columns to utc_timestamp() value.  Even setting the value in a trigger for CRT_TS, the value is overridden.

Thanks for any clarity you can provide.

Comment: If you look at the table definition in the database, i suspect it has a 'default value' of 'current_timestamp'. manual: [Automatic Initialization and Updating for TIMESTAMP and DATETIME](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: It works as expected in SQL Fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4fb25) -- which is that it returns an error.  The error should be in the `insert` (because `CRT_TS` and `UPD_TS`) are not given values, but MySQL waits until the `select` to report the error.

Comment: Ryan, Thank you for the answer.  It is interesting that the UPT_TS column was defaulted to all zeros, while the CRT_TS column which was defined exactly the same in my script, but was defaulted to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP.  Per the documenation you pointed me to and some other posts I found based on that, I'll set my database's calendar to UTC and default both columns to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in my table definitions.